# How to specify Stopwords in Elasticsearch mapping using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, stop-words

I have this `python` code where I first create a `Elasticsearch` mapping and then after data is inserted I do searching for that data:

```
# Create Data mapping
data_mapping = {
        "mappings": {
            (doc_type): {
                "properties": {
                    "data_id": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "fields": {
                            "stemmed": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "english"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "data":{
                        "type": "array",
                        "fields": {
                            "stemmed": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "english"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "resp": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "fields": {
                            "stemmed": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "english"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "update": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "fields": {
                            "stemmed": {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "analyzer": "english"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
#Search
data_search = {
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {

                    "match": {
                        'data': question
                    }
                },
                "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "update",
                    "modifier": "log2p"
                }
            }
        }
        }
response = es.search(index=doc_type, body=data_search)
```

Now what I am unable to figure out where and how to specify `stopwords` in the above code? [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) link gives an example of using `stopwords` but I am unable to relate it to my code. Do I need to specify in the `data mapping` section, search section or both? And how do I specify it?

Any example help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:** Based on some comments suggestion is to add either `analysis` section or `settings` sections but I am not sure how should I add those to the `mapping` section I have written above.

Comment: You are missing `analysis` section of the link you provided. there you can define custom analyzers and set stop work token filters for that custom analyzer.

Comment: you missed `settings` section and for english analyzer go to [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer).

Comment: @MohammadMazraeh how can I add the analysis section to the mapping section I have in my code above?

Comment: @AshwaniShakya how can I add the settings section to the mapping section I have in my code above?

Comment: `PUT/_settings { "mappings": {you_mapping}, "settings": {your settings}}` for more info follow this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html)

Comment: @AshwaniShakya In my current `mappings` in above code I have `analyzer` added for language. So when I add `settings` section what do I specify in the `analyzer` section of mappings? Do I remove it or do I update it?